# Spring Hibernate Many To Many database pre-populate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa

So I have 2 entities - **Post** and **Tag** and there is a **many to many** relation between them. I also have a CSV file and need to pre-populate the database (it contains post details including the ids of the matching Tag entities). Moreover following DDD, the Post entity is the Aggregate root with its PostRepository. Given below are the java classes: -

```
@Entity
public class Post{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascadeType = {MERGE, PERSIST})
  @JoinTable(name = "post_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
  private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

  // getters, setters ommited.

  public void addTag(Tag tag){
    tags.add(tag);
    tag.getPosts().add(this);
  }
}

@Entity
public class Tag{
@Id
private long id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
  private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

  // getters, setters ommited.
  }
}
```

Repository interface below : -

```
public interface PostRepo extends Repository<Post, Long>{
  void save(Post p);
}
```

Database pre-loading code below : -

```
@Service
public class Service {

  @Inject
  private PostRepo repo; 

  @PostConstruct
  void init(){
   // parse CSV file and get a Stream<String[]> stream

      stream.foreach( splits -> {
        long tagId = Long.parseLong(splits[0]);
         Post post = new Post();
         post.add(new Tag(tagId);
         repo.save(post);
     }
  }
}
```

While prepopulating the DB using the

> PostRepo::save(post)

method I am running into a Primary key constraint validation error, and I think the reason behind that being while adding a Post entity I am also trying to add a new Tag with the same id as a pre-existing Tag entity.

So here is my question how can I do it correctly without adding a TagRepository and using the saveOrUpdate method of the TagRepository please?

Comment: Please show your complete code there you saving your entities.

Comment: Code from `long tagId =` to `repo.save(post);` is in the loop, right? So every iteration you try to persist `Tag` with the same id (`splits[0]`)?

Comment: I see you have added `stream.foreach( splits -> {`.. Are you sure that every splits[0] contain unique value? I suggest to add `@GeneratedValue` to `tag.id` and add another field, for example, `tag.externalId` for saving external id from `splits[0]`...

Comment: ofcourse they r not unique, thats the reason behind the @ManyToMany association.

And the reason behind the question is not use another auto-gen tag, which would break data integrity as each tag id points to a unique tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```java
@Component
public class DataLoader implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autoware
    private PostRepo repo;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        // parse CSV file and get a Stream<String[]> stream

        Map<Long, Tag> tagCache = new HashMap<>(); // The cache for persisted tags

        /* Outer loop by posts */ {

            Post post = new Post();

            stream.forEach(splits -> {
                Long tagId = Long.parseLong(splits[0]);

                // Get already persisted Tag or create new one
                Tag tag = tagCache.getOrDefault(tagId, new Tag(tagId));

                post.addTag(tag);
            });

            Post savedPost = repo.save(post);
            List<Tag> tags = savedPost.getTags(); // get persisted tags
            tags.forEach(tag -> tagCache.put(tag.getId(), tag)); // put it into the cache
        }
    }
}
```

If entity already persisted (for example some Tag) we cannot create it again - this will be just another entity, so we must get it from the DB, then reuse.

So here we use a simple 'cache' to store persisted Tags.
I think this should work.

A little bit [info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-command-line-runner):

> If you need to run some specific code once the SpringApplication has started, you can implement the ApplicationRunner or CommandLineRunner interfaces. Both interfaces work in the same way and offer a single run method which will be called just before SpringApplication.run(…​) completes.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, unfortunately your answer isnt a solution (it would fail as a save of Post would result in a cascaded save of a Tag irrespective of what you cache), I just wanted to thank you for the CLR reminder - something I missed previously.

What we really need to do is while saving Post need to figure out if Tag is already persisted (without using a Tag repo) and needs to be updated rather than persisted afresh and inform JPA to act accordingly for the Tag enity while persisting Post always.